# Optimal MySQL indexes and query for selecting 3 rows based on 3 conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization

I have a MySQL table `products` with ~10k rows looking like this:

```
+----+-----+--------+------+---------+
| id | cat | color  | size |  descr  |
+----+-----+--------+------+---------+
|  1 |   1 | red    |    1 | Lorem 1 |
|  2 |   1 | green  |    2 | Lorem 2 |
|  3 |   2 | orange |    1 | Lorem 3 |
|  4 |   2 | blue   |    3 | Lorem 4 |
+----+-----+--------+------+---------+
```

I need to select 3 specific records based on 3 conditions with a single MySQL query. There are always will be exactly 3 records satisfying all 3 conditions.

Here is the query I came up with that works:

```sql
SELECT 
  cat, 
  color, 
  size, 
  descr 
FROM 
  products 
WHERE 
  (
    cat = 1 
    AND color = 'red' 
    AND size = 1
  ) 
  OR (
    cat = 2 
    and color = 'orange' 
    and size = 1
  ) 
  OR (
    cat = 2 
    AND color = 'blue' 
    AND size = 3
  )
```

Question 1: Is this the most optimal query to retrieve the 3 records based on 3 conditions?

Question 2: What would be the optimal index(s) structure for this table?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create an index on `(cat, color, size)`. The order of columns in the index doesn't matter in this case, since you use `=` for the comparisons in all cases.

MySQL's [`IN()` predicate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in) supports row constructor comparison syntax, and current versions of MySQL do support [index optimization for row constructor expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/row-constructor-optimization.html) (old versions of MySQL didn't, but those versions are all past their end-of-life by now).

```
SELECT 
  category, 
  color, 
  size, 
  descr 
FROM 
  products 
WHERE (cat, color, size) IN (
    (1, 'red', 1),
    (2, 'orange', 1),
    (2, 'blue', 3)
)
```